# How to handle highly skewed percentage data

Tags: regression, predictive-models, skewness, percentage

I am trying to make a prediction model (explanation would be nice but mainly predicting as accurately as possible is more important, for now). My independent variables are all percentages (quantity of various ingredients) and my dependent variable is also a percentage (but of a physical response - specifically shrinkage, literally how much the thing shrinks during a process). In other words I'm trying to say - a sample with percentage of ingredients A %, B %, and C %, will shrink X %.

I am finding it hard to get a good prediction using this data. I think the cause is due to either the fact that some of the independent variables are highly skewed - e.g. because the quantity is very close to zero. Or that the dependent variable is highly skewed - but at around 12 % due to some physical limit, not because it's rubbing up against 0 % or 100 %. For example, the dependent variable:

[image: Distribution of dependent variable]

Random forest, SVM and xgboost all seem to predict *almost* a single value (i.e. they seem extremely regularised towards the ~ 12 % upper limit). Regularised regression (glmnet) does better, but the residuals are definitely not homoscedastic: a plot of predicted values vs true values is pretty curved.

I've tried doing a logit transform and although that has improved the regression a little, it obviously hasn't addressed the skewness. I'm thinking of trying something simple like a Box-Cox transform, but I've no idea whether it's reasonable to do that - nor whether I should do it pre or post logit (or forget logit altogether). I'd really appreciate some advice on that - or any better ideas.

Thanks.

Edit as requested:

A pairs plot (note the data originates from a French colleague so retrait = shrinkage):

[image: Pairs plot of all variables]

And a plot of only the variables with which shrinkage has an r > 0.5:

[image: Only decent correlations]

Comment: As I see it the main reason for transformation here is, or should be, getting relationships closer to linear. Regression-type models don't assume anything about the marginal distribution of any variable, whether outcome or predictor.  In practice skewness may be tied up with other reasons to transform. Being close to zero could be tied up with nonlinearity.  What I would most want to see is a scatterplot matrix with all your variables.

Comment: @NickCox thanks, have added a full pairs plot plus a reduced version showing only the parameters that are correlated with shrinkage where r > 0.5.

Comment: Regularized regression (glmnet) has no assumptions on the residuals, since inference is usally not done. What is your goal? Prediction? If so, this is not really a concern, although it might be improved.

Comment: Thanks for the plots. For proportions close to 0 or to 1 it is sometimes forgotten that square root and square are simple transformations that respect limits and can tidy up a graph. Logits can be splendidly appropriate for many problems -- but can stretch far too much if any values are very small or very large in that interval, and indeed are at best awkward if any 0s or 1s are observed. I have no expertise on the physics (or chemistry) of shrinkage, but my guess is that logit scale is not quite right.

Comment: Pedantic detail: statistical people would say _variables_ where you say _parameters_.

Comment: @NickCox ah yes, sorry - it's a cross over from how the other people in the project talk about things (I am having to try and "translate" a lot and missed that). Ok thanks. In my limited knowledge I thought logit might be sensible given they're percentages, but I wasn't very confident about that. I'll try your recommendation(s) - thanks.

Comment: Often that's right about logit -- many of us, me included, have written papers with a main theme "think about using logit scale for analysis".  Much depends on the exact range of your data. If shrinkage is in practice never below about 0.01 square root may be too tame and logit more helpful. If shrinkage is ever say 0.001 the comparison may be reversed.  I'd prefer a quantile plot to a histogram because the binning leaves such details ambiguous.

Comment: @NickCox just in case you're interested. I tried the sqrt and I also tried it on only independent variables, or only the dependent variable, or both. I also re-tried no transformation. I could swear I tried that already but maybe I defaulted to percentages = logit. Some surprises (for me at least), but generally the cross-validated rmse goes as: sqrt(independents) =< none < sqrt(dependent) << sqrt(both independent & dependent). I haven't tried the independents separately, yet. Logit is generally between the last two. I think probably I'll stick with none for now! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Note that RMSE is on scale of the outcome, so transformed when the outcome is transformed.

Comment: Absolutely, I did inverse the transform after prediction / before calculation of rmse.